# Task<TResult>.ConfigureAwait(false) resumes on captured context

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have below block of code:

```
Task task2Seconds = Wait2Seconds();
Task task5Seconds = Wait5Seconds();

await task5Seconds;
await task2Seconds.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

1. The first task await is considered to resume on the same (captured) context, but it takes 5 seconds.
2. The second task await is configured to not resume on captured context and it just takes 2 seconds.
3. Result is after second task await, it still resumes on captured context.

I don't understand the underlying logic, can anyone explain to me?

Thanks
Khoi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you are telling .NET that when resuming execution after the `await`, the framework is not *required* to resume execution in the same context. But that is not the same as telling the framework that it *is* required to *not* resume in the same context.

Your second `await` is awaiting a task that has already completed. As such, the continuation can be executed immediately and synchronously, i.e. without relinquishing control of the thread. So, your code remains in the same context in that case.

It's not that the `await` is specifically returning you to the original context. Rather, it's just that it had no reason to leave that context, and so you're still there when the `await` completes.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü where is it?

Comment: @Khoi: he's deleted his answers, because neither were correct. He was mistaken about what was going on in your code.

Comment: Thank @PeterDuniho. I was reading his comments too but it was not correct, but I think he has a good learning from you. Me too :)

Comment: @Khoi, Like peter pointed out, I was mistaken but it was a good learning for me. But he was a strict teacher :) I did not notice that you start the tasks as soon as you created them. `Task task2Seconds = Wait2Seconds();
Task task5Seconds = Wait5Seconds();`